# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module - Ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I'm working on Ionic 2 project with the rootPage set to AuthPage. Later on, I created another page named SplashPage (through the console), but when I set the rootPage to SplashPage, I hit the error `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./pages/splash/splash"` (app.bundle.js:3188). Any clue of what's wrong?

app.ts

```
import {App, IonicApp, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ListPage} from './pages/list/list';
import {WishListPage} from './pages/wishlist/wishlist';
import {AuthPage} from './pages/auth/auth';
import {SplashPage} from './pages/splash/splash';

@App({
    templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
    config: {}, // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
    providers: [UserService]
})
class MyApp {
    rootPage: any = SplashPage;
    pages: Array<{title: string, component: any, user: string}>;
    user: any;
    constructor(private app: IonicApp, private platform: Platform,
                private userService: UserService) {
        this.initializeApp();
        this.user = userService;

        // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
        this.pages = [

            // No need to include this since the user shouldn't see
            // the login page again until their session/token expires
            //{ title: 'Login', component: AuthPage },

            // Since we don't need to fear our user manually navigating
            // via url, why not manage naviagtion permissions with simple
            // template conditionals `*ngIf`
            { title: 'Wishlist', component: WishListPage, user: "shopper"}, // SHOPPER
            { title: 'Current Orders', component: ListPage, user: "shopper" }, // SHOPPER
            { title: 'Orders', component: ListPage, user: "boxer" }, // BOXER
            { title: 'Profile', component: ProfilePage, user:"both" } // BOTH
        ];

    }
```

splash.ts

```
import {OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgIf} from 'angular2/common';
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

// @PAGES
import {AuthPage} from '../auth/auth';

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/splash/splash.html',
    directives: [NgIf],
    providers: []
})

export class SplashPage {
    constructor() { console.log("@AuthPage: __init__"); }
}
```

Comment: did you find it? same error here, thanks

Comment: @AlejandroLora not yet :/

Comment: it might be useless but try '@Component' decorator instead of '@Page' decorator and let us know..

Answer (score -3):

it looks like `app.ts` you are calling the class spalsh but the actual class name is `SplashPage`

so try, renaming `SplashPage` to `Splash` in #splash.ts

Comment: I doubt that's the problem. Otherwise, I had to renamed the class AuthPage to Auth and WishListPage to WishList (both are working fine). Btw, SplashPage was auto created via the command `ionic g page splash`